# Plausibility of combining Kod and Komodo Edit?

Tags: cocoa, open-source, gecko, komodoedit

I would like to know how difficult it would be to merge the well-designed [Kod](http://kodapp.com) editor and the powerfully-built [Komodo Edit](http://activestate.com/komodo-edit) together. I'd like to think it could turn into a native Mountain Lion programming editor with a simple interface (focus on elegance) and yet with powerful editing features.

Kod is a native OS X app, while Komodo is a cross-platform app based on Mozilla code. Both are under "open-source" licenses - Kod's license seems very permissive, and Komodo's is... long. I'm still deciphering it, but it seems like one could take code and put it into a new project.

I see this as becoming a new open source project: Kodmodo. I just don't know how compatible the source could be between the two programs.

Comment: Sublime Text is the very product I envisioned with this, so I think I'll just start using that instead! No use open-sourcing the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kod looks interesting but quite young.  An editor without a preferences section for keybindings and color schemes?  Might develop into an interesting project (node.js based). Quite a bit of Komodo Edit is done in javascript.

Alas, the main implementation language for Komodo is Python and the interfaces (opening files etc) are Mozilla. Kod uses OSX goodies and states on their main page that

> Written from scratch with modern OS X 10.6 APIs **providing maximum OS integration** (empahsis added)

It would be near impossible to integrate [OpenKomodo](http://www.openkomodo.com/) and [Eric](http://eric-ide.python-projects.org/) where both use python for development and macros and scintilla for the edit component.  Komodo and Kod will never happen because they start from different places entirely.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the thorough answer, I really appreciate it.